# Why Crystal Report Formula is not working to Group Data

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I am using formula fields and have created this `formula` to group data on the basis of `null or not`. but it is not working and always group data in just one `Completed` group. Why ?

```
 if (Not IsNull({MRSReportProject_MRSReportClass.Actiontaken})) 
    and (IsNull({MRSReportProject_MRSReportClass.actioncomplete})) then "Pending"

    else if (Not IsNull({MRSReportProject_MRSReportClass.actioncomplete})) then "Completed"

else "Nothing";
```

Comment: In you report options, haven't you accidentally left option `convert null values to default` checked?

Comment: My advice would be to manipulate your data external to crystal reports. Any calculated fields included. Then if something goes wrong you are working with c# rather than crystal.

Comment: @Arvo where to check that ? i see no report options button ?

Comment: @Arvo and what if i check empty string instead of null ? like if `abc="" ...` but then how to check not empty string ? this doesnt work `abc != ""`

Comment: @Arvo and no i haven't checked that option !

Comment: In Crystal syntax, inequality operator is `<>`.

Comment: @Arvo thanks bro using inequality sign worked !

Comment: I converted this to answer, you can act on that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your null values are not null values.

One reason could be Crystal Report option `convert null values to default` - if this is checked, then formulas don't see null values, but empty strings or number 0, depend on field type.

Another possibility is that already your data source does not return null values.

You should then use simple comparison operators (`=`, `<>`) to compare values; if sometimes null values can occur, then you must consider all combinations (using both comparison operators and isnull() functions). I have sometimes used intermediate variables or formulas for eliminating null values, simplifies code a bit (some formulas can be pages long).